# How to extract parts of complex configuration with CONFIG generator expression in CMake

Tags: cmake

In our project, we have a large number of configurations stemming from a large variety of target hardware types multiplied by few modes.

To avoid unneeded details let's just assume that the configurations have form `<hw>_<mode>` were

- `<hw>` is one of: `A`, `B` or `C`,
- `<mode>` is one of: `1`, `2` or `3`.

Furthermore, to remain close to actual case let's assume that `A_3` and `C_1` are unsupported exceptions. (However, I don't think it matters here.)

Which leaves us with 3 x 3 - 2 = 7 supported configurations.

---

Now, we would like to make settings (amongst others also the path to compiler and sysroot) depend on the configuration. Also, some sources should be included only in some configurations. And we would prefer to do it based on parts of the configuration.

For example, we would like to use `/this/g++` for all `A_*` configurations and `/that/g++` for all other. Or we would like to add `mode2.cpp` file for all `*_2` configurations but not others.

It is a simple task if we use [`CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html). We can split it with regex ([`string(REGEX MATCH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/string.html#regex-match)) and have variables with each part. Then simple [`if`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/if.html) does the job.

However, such approach is not friendly with multi-config generators (it seems currently those are only Visual Studio and Xcode). To play nicely with multi-config generators, AFAIK, we would have to use [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html).

---

The problem is, however, that I see no way to extract parts for the configuration (`CONFIG`) in the generator expressions.

For example, I can do this:

```
add_executable(my_prog
    source_1.cpp
# ...
    source_n.cpp
    $<$<CONFIG:A_2>:mode2.cpp>
    $<$<CONFIG:B_2>:mode2.cpp>
    $<$<CONFIG:C_2>:mode2.cpp>
)
```

but this doesn't look like a maintainable approach considering that sooner or later we will be adding new hardware types (or removing obsolete ones).

Is there any way to do some form of matching in generator expression?

The only workaround I found out so far is to use an approach like this:

```
set(CONFIG_IS_MODE_2 $<OR:$<CONFIG:A_2>,$<CONFIG:B_2>,$<CONFIG:C_2>>)

add_executable(my_target
    source_1.cpp
# ...
    source_n.cpp
    $<${CONFIG_IS_MODE_2}:mode2.cpp>
)
```

which at least allows centralizing those expressions and when new hardware type is added there is a single place to update. However, still, there are many variables to update.

---

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

With [`target_sources()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html) command and a [`function()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/function.html) you could still use a regex to match your configurations.

This would look something like in this example code:

```perl
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(TestConfigRegEx)

function(my_add_sources_by_config_regex _target _regex)
    foreach(_config IN LISTS CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
        if (_config MATCHES "${_regex}")
            target_sources(${_target} PRIVATE $<$<CONFIG:${_config}>:${ARGN}>)
        endif()
    endforeach()
endfunction()

file(WRITE main.cpp "int main() { return 0; }")
file(WRITE modeRelease.cpp "")

add_executable(my_target main.cpp)

my_add_sources_by_config_regex(my_target Release modeRelease.cpp)
```

But that gives me an error from CMake version 3.11.1 `Visual Studio 15 2017` generator side:

```
Target "my_target" has source files which vary by configuration.  This is
not supported by the "Visual Studio 15 2017" generator.

Config "Debug":

  .../main.cpp

Config "Release":

  .../main.cpp
  .../modeRelease.cpp
```

Strange enough it still generates the solution.

---

**Alternatives**

- The classic one would be adding a define containing the configuration and handle the differences in the C/C++ code with `#if` checks
- You differentiate not per configuration but with additional targets (like `my_target` and `my_target_2`)

Comment: This seems to be a feature missing in the generator. Visual Studio itself has no problems with excluding/including source files or even entire projects depending on configuration. Actually, it is quite nice to see that there is a file but  it is "inactive" in currently selected configuration.

Comment: I just checked this with VS 2017 and CMake 3.9.3. Indeed generating the project issues many warnings (not just once...). And indeed the project is generated none the less. And it does use the "Exclude From Build" property as I described in comment above!

Comment: I have made an issue for this problem (of "fake errors"): https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18233.